# Asp.net ImageResizer with multiple SQLServer plugins

Tags: imageresizer

How I can using SQLReader plugins with different connection string because I want to store file in multiple different tables. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install multiple instances of the SqlReader plugin, each with a different set of queries and a different route prefix.